# How Enable cookie-based persistence in a backend Haproxy even browser disabled cookies

Tags: session-cookies, haproxy

I just started using haproxy (1.4) for loadbalance. Through reading the Configuration Manual, i could using cookie insert to insert a cookie in the  server responses, but this requires the browser to enable cookies. Besides after  googled hours , i could not find anything about the Arguments  details of cookie rewrite. So i tried liked this in the haproxy.cfg

```
   backend app                                                                                                  

      balance roundrobin                                                                  
      cookie SERVERID rewrite                                                             
      mode http                                                                           
      server  web1 192.168.1.133:80 cookie web1 maxconn 32 check inter 5000 rise 2 fall 5 weight 1
      server  web2 192.168.1.134:80 cookie web2 maxconn 32 check inter 5000 rise 2 fall 5 weight 2
```

but i can't find anything in the firebug related cookies.
So i wondered if anyone can give something about  **cookie-based persistence in a backend, no matter whether the browser enabled cookies or not, without using anything tools like memcached , etc, just configuring the configuration file.**

Answer (score 0):

You can look at doing something with a "stick table" https://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/stick_table

You will have to make sure that your stick table is synced to all load balancers or make sure that the end user traffic lands on the same load balancer every time. I know that later versions of haproxy (1.5.17+) support syncing the stick table, I do not know about earlier versions.